# Storing HTML, CSS, JS for individual users on sites like jsfiddle.net and cssdeck.com

Tags: javascript, html, css, storage

Does anyone have insight into how html, css, and js are stored for each user on sites like [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net) and [cssdeck.com](http://www.cssdeck.com), i.e. sites that let users create/store their own front-end projects?

Are they stored as text strings in the user table/collection in the db, or are they stored as separate files? Does anyone know the best practice here?

Thanks!

Comment: you *could* gzip it and store in the DB; that's probably the route I'd go. files should be pretty tiny, the 4kb overhead of storing it on disk would probably cost more...but I'm no DB expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The founder of jsfiddle answered this question around a year ago.

From the answer:

> It's SQL, structure is generated with Django's ORM. Pasties and versions use separate tables. Currently code is saved in the same table due to my bad design. It's going to change in the near future.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283257/how-does-jsfiddle-work